# Stop scrolling at last image in html

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have the following html-

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
   <style type="text/css">
    .style1 {
        width: 2454px;

    }
   </style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="5964" border="0" cellspacing="13">
  <tr>
   <td width="3484"><img src="images/square.jpg" width="850" height="534" /
   <img src="images/circle.jpg" width="850" height="534" /></td>
   <td class="style1"><img src="images/rectangle.png" width="1134" height="534" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

When I view this page in IE the horizontal scrollbar goes much further than it should, whereas I need it to stop on the last image `rectangle.png`.

I have tried to alter the CSS making the column width set to auto but this did not work, and also the table width. How can I get round this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing with all of those explicit `widths`, but you should probably take a look at the math of the widths.

Comment: Tip: Change `<imgsrc="images/circle.jpg"` to `<img src="images/circle.jpg"`.

Comment: http://shouldiusetablesforlayout.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first column have a width of 3484px  and your rectangle image have a width of 1134px. So at minimun it will be 4618px even if you change the width in the CSS. ( about 4 times the width of my current screen).

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#container {
width:100%; // set width to what you want
margin:0 auto; // if you want to center on page
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<table width="5964" border="0" cellspacing="13">
<tr>
<td width="3484"><img src="images/square.jpg" width="850" height="534" /
<img src="images/circle.jpg" width="850" height="534" /></td>
<td><img src="images/rectangle.png" width="1134" height="534" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Try this and see if it helps you if you have your content contained within the screen it should help with scrolling. I have solved the same problem in the past this way. Hope it helps good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the input however it still has a massive gap at the end of the screen, any other thoughts?

Comment: Have you solved the problem if not send me a link to the page in question and I will see if I can help you out.